# How to Enable first Text Field when when first checkbox is checked

Tags: php, jquery

My sample table:

```
 ____________________________________________________________________________
  | Select All |  Quantity  | Name & Description  |        Remarks           |
  ____________________________________________________________________________
  |   []           |    2       |    BallPen          | text field here      |
______________________________________________________________________________
  |   []           |    10      |    Pencil           | text field here      |
  ____________________________________________________________________________
```

I want to enable the first text field when the user click the first checkbox which Name & description = " BallPen" or enable the second text field when the second checkbox is clicked..the default value of the text field is disabled. How can I do that?

Table values is from my database.

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['faculty'])){
         $faculty = $_POST['faculty'];
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM are A, are_item AI WHERE AI.Reque = '$faculty' AND A.Reque = '$faculty' AND A.are_no = AI.are_no");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
      $are_no = $row["are_no"];

      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE id = '$faculty'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $middle = $row['middlename'];
            $last = $row['lastname'];
            $name = $firstname . " " .$middle . " " . $last;
                  }           
        echo" Item(s) ownned by " . $name  ;


    echo '<table class="table text-center" style="border-collapse:collapse">';

    echo "<thead>";
        echo"<th align = 'center'><font size='1'>Select All</font><input type='checkbox' id='selectall' onClick='selectAll(this)'/></th>";
        echo "<th align = 'center'>Quantity</th>";
        echo "<th align = 'center'>Unit</th>";
        echo "<th align = 'center'>Name & Description</th>";
        echo "<th align = 'center'>PR No.</th>";
        echo "<th align = 'center'>Date Acquired</th>";
        echo "<th align = 'center'>Property Number</th>";
        echo "<th align = 'center'>Number of items</th>";

    echo "</thead>";
      echo "<tbody>";
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblitems I, are_item AI ,tblpur P WHERE AI.are_no = '$are_no' AND I.itemid = AI.itemid AND I.pr_no = P.pr_no");
             $k = 1;
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
          $item_id = $row["itemid"];

            $check = 'check' . $k;
          $quantity = $row["quantity"];
          $unit = $row["unit"];
          $description = $row["description"];
          $purchase_no = $row["pr_no"];
          $property = $row["property_no"];
          $date_acquired = $row["date_acquired"];
         $stat = $row["stat"];

             if($stat == '1'){

             }
             else
             {

            echo "<tr>";

            ?>
             <td><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value = "<?php echo $row['itemid']; ?>"></td>
            <?php
            echo "<td align = 'center'>$quantity</td>";
            echo "<td align = 'center'>$unit</td>";
            echo "<td align = 'center'>$description</td>";
            echo "<td align = 'center'>$purchase_no</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$property</td>";
             echo "<td align='center'>$date_acquired</td>";




             ?>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name = "<?php echo $noof; ?>" maxlength=5 ></td>
              <?php
              echo "</tr>";

          }
      }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
     $k++;
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: It'd be a lot better if you pasted your HTML so we could provide you with a Javascript solution that works with your code.

Comment: Uhm guys my problem was solved.. so how can i mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a table then the generic solution could be something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("table").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", "change", function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

I've done the example with [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) incase you might be adding extra rows with jQuery/AJAX in the future.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTw4L/) for a demo.

Comment: @DamWoo You're welcome. I'm glad the solution worked for you :)

Comment: i used the same script in http://jsfiddle.net/XTw4L/ and my echo"<th align = 'center'><label>Select All</label><input type='checkbox' name='selectall' class='select-all'></th>";

Comment: @DamWoo did you add a class `checkbox` to your checkboxes in your table rows? In the fiddle you can see, that the checkboxes in every row has a `class="checkbox"` and the select all targets those classes. Also the select all checkbox has a class `select-all` which is also used to trigger the event for selecting all checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to accomplish this.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="mode" data-for="text1"></td>
    <td>Blah blah blah</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="text1" disabled></td>
</tr>

<script>
    $('.mode').click( function() {
        var f = $(this).attr('data-for');
        $('#' + f).attr('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'))
    } );
</script>
```

A check all option

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all">

<script>
    $('#all').click( function() {
        $('table input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'))
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Will it work for multiple checkboxes? my values is from my database so the count of checkbox depends on the number of rows my query found

Comment: Yes of course...  for each row, make sure the value of data-for attribute is the same as the matching id on the text field

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="chk" /></th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
        <th> Name & Description</th>
        <th> Remarks </th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" /></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td> BallPen </td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" /></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td> BallPen </td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" /></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td> BallPen </td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

jQuery Code

```
$(function(){ 
    $('input.chk').click(function(){
       $(this).closest('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').children('input').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: uh its kinda cool.. can you do the same in select all checkbox.. all text field are enabled when selectall checkbox is clicked?

Comment: @DamWoo Please see fiffle http://jsfiddle.net/rohitbatham/Ta3ku/3/   and upvote if your issue get solved.